# Capturar value de select de formulario en otra pagina y localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intento capturar el valor de un select que pasa 2 values 1 y 2 de un formulario hacia otra pagina y en localstorage he intentado pero siempre me manda solo el value 1 no consigo enviar el value 2. por otra parte estoy intentando cuando esos valores llegan a la otra pagina por loclastorge que los valores se mantengan permanentes y al refresacar me retorna al formulario.
Gracias. ya intente varios meteodos pero no lo logro. ***estoy usando redux con react***. gracias por el apoyo. puedo enviar mas detalles si se nesecita.

```js
// formulario
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { getLoginAction } from "../../redux/auth";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
export const FormLogin = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user, pass, cliente_gg, cliente_pv } = useSelector((store) => store.auth);

  console.log(cliente_gg, cliente_pv, 'clientes');

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLoginAction());
    console.log(getLoginAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    usuario: "",
    password: "",
    options: "",
  });
  const { usuario, password, options } = formValues;

  

  let users = [
    { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" }
  ];

  users.unshift({
    value: "",
    label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]"
  })
  //console.log(users[1].value);

  const [captchaValido, cambiarCaptchaValido] = useState(null);
  //const [usuarioValido, cambiarUsuarioValido] = useState(false);
  const [errorUsuario, setErrorUsuario] = useState(null);
  const [errorPassword, setErrorPasword] = useState(null);
  const [errorSelect, seterrorSelect] = useState('');
  const [errorCredencial, seterrorCredencial] = useState(null);

  const captcha = useRef(null);
  const onCaptcha = () => {
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(true);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    } else {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(false);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(false);
    }

    if (!usuario.trim()) {
      setErrorUsuario("El campo usuario es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(usuario)) {
      setErrorUsuario("Ingrese un email valido.");
      return;
    }

    if (!password.trim()) {
      setErrorPasword("El campo password es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (
      !/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ]){8,15}$/.test(
        password
      )
    ) {
      setErrorPasword("Ingrese un formato Valido");
      return;
    }

    if (options === "") {
      seterrorSelect("Debe seleccionar una opción");
      return;
    } 

  

    if (user === usuario && pass === password && (cliente_gg === users[1].value || cliente_pv === users[2].value)) {
      history.push("/proveedor");
    } else {
      seterrorCredencial("usuario y contraseña incorrectos");
      return;
    }

    setErrorUsuario(null);
    setErrorPasword(null);
    seterrorCredencial("");
    seterrorSelect('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {errorCredencial ? (
            <span className="text-danger">{errorCredencial}</span>
          ) : null}
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="usuario"
              placeholder="Usuario"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={usuario}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorUsuario(null)}
            />
            {errorUsuario ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorUsuario}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              autoComplete="off"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorPasword(null)}
            />
            {errorPassword ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorPassword}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <select
              className="form-select"
              name="options"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              value={options}
              onBlur={()=>seterrorSelect('')}
            >
              {users.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                    {item.label}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
            {errorSelect ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorSelect}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="text-center mb-2">
            <a href="/#" className="text-decoration-none text-secondary forgot">
              Olvidé mi contraseña
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="recaptcha">
            <ReCAPTCHA
              ref={captcha}
              sitekey="6LebBoUcAAAAAAQrF5ZeUIRn7vGecVJ5FEG5A5Ls"
              onChange={onCaptcha}
            />
          </div>
          {captchaValido === false && (
            <div className="text-danger">Por favor acepta el captcha</div>
          )}
          <div className="d-grid gap-2">
            <button type="submit" className="btn bg-button block subtitle">
              INGRESAR
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="text-center mt-2">
          <a href="/#" className="text-decoration questions">
            PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* {usuarioValido && console.log("Redirect o cambia vista")} */}
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
//pagina donde se recibe el valor del select

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Logo } from "../components/atoms/Logo";
import { getLogoutAction } from "../redux/auth";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Proveedores = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    history.push("/login");
    dispatch(getLogoutAction());
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user, pass, cliente_gg, cliente_pv } = useSelector((store) => store.auth);

  //const {gg, pv} = useSelector((store) => store.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    localStorage.setItem("password", JSON.stringify(pass));
    localStorage.setItem("cliente", JSON.stringify( cliente_gg || cliente_pv ));
    
  }, [user, pass, cliente_gg, cliente_pv]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6">
            <Logo />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6"></div>

          <div className="content-box-internas mt-4">
            <span className="nav-item nav-link-text-info">
              <p>{user}</p>
              <p>{pass}</p>
              <p>{'Cliente' ? cliente_gg : cliente_pv }</p>
              <button onClick={handleLogout} className="nav-item nav-link btn">
                Logout
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: useForm() es un customHook?